# Regex to split Spanish lastnames in first lastname and second lastname

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

My goal is to write a python 3 function that takes lastnames as row from a csv and splits them correctly into lastname_1 and lastname_2.

Spanish names have the following structure: `firstname + lastname_1 + lastname_2`

Forgettin about the firstname, I would like a code that splits a lastname in these 2 categories (lastname_1, lastname_2) Which is the challenge?

Sometimes the lastname(s) have prepositions.

- DE BLAS ZAPATA "de blas" ist the first lastname and "Zapata" the second lastname
- MATIAS DE LA MANO "Matias" is lastname_1, "de la mano" lastname_2
- LOPEZ FERNANDEZ DE VILLAVERDE Lopez Fernandez is lastname_1, de villaverda lastname_2
- DE MIGUEL DEL CORRAL De Miguel is lastname_1, del corral lastname_2 More: VIDAL DE LA PEÑA SOLIS Vidal is surtname_1, de la pena solis surname_2
- MONTAVA DEL ARCO Montava is surname_1 Del Arco surname_2

and the list could go on and on.

I am currently stuck and I found [this code in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701374/parsing-spanish-family-name) but I struggle to understand the main idea behind it to translate it to python 3.

```
import re

preposition_lst = ['DE LO ', 'DE LA ', 'DE LAS ', 'DEL ', 'DELS ', 'DE LES ', 'DO ', 'DA ', 'DOS ', 'DAS', 'DE ']
cases = ["DE BLAS ZAPATA", "MATIAS DE LA MANO", "LOPEZ FERNANDEZ DE VILLAVERDE", "DE MIGUEL DEL CORRAL", "VIDAL DE LA PEÑA", "MONTAVA DEL ARCO", "DOS CASAS VALLE"]

for case in cases:
  for prep in preposition_lst:
    m = re.search(f"(.*)({prep}[A-ZÀ-ÚÄ-Ü]+)", case, re.I) # re.I makes it case insensitive
    try:
      print(m.groups())
      print(prep)
    except:
      pass
```

Comment: The Perl solution you linked to just validates names with `re.search(r'^((?:De |Del |De La |De Los |De Las )?\w+)( (?:De |Del |De La |De Los |De Las )?\w+)?( de (?:De |Del |De La |De Los |De Las )?\w+)?$', text)`. It is not [quite working](https://regex101.com/r/3LBu5L/1) for your examples.

Comment: I do not understand the approach which I would really like to rather than copy-pasting... but it also does not deliver the correct results...

Comment: And here is your prepositions list incorporated into that regex: https://regex101.com/r/3LBu5L/2

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Ts2MSz

Comment: Before going to the regex details, I looked at the solutions and LOPEZ FERNANDEZ DE VILLAVERDE is not correct... because "Lopez Fernandez" should be lastname_1 and "Villaverde" lastname_2. So 2 parts, not 3

Comment: Looks like another one who hasn't read [Falsehoods programmers believe about names.](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: What if you were given (and please forgive any ignorance of Spanish last names here) a last name of "Lopez Fernandez Zapata"? How would you tell where to split the two last names? This doesn't seem like an easy problem to solve generally and programmatically, because as tripleee mentions: names are complicated.

Comment: Indeed, names are complicated and to Pranav's point, since you removed the preposition "DE" I would no longer know where to split.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
import re

preposition_lst = ['DE','LO','LA','LAS','DEL','DELS','LES','DO','DA','DOS','DAS']
cases = ["DE BLAS ZAPATA", "MATIAS DE LA MANO", "LOPEZ FERNANDEZ DE VILLAVERDE", "DE MIGUEL DEL CORRAL", "VIDAL DE LA PEÑA", "MONTAVA DEL ARCO", "DOS CASAS VALLE"]



def last_name(name):
    case=re.findall(r'\w+',name)
    res=list(filter(lambda x: x not in preposition_lst,case))
    return res

list_final =[]
for case in cases:
    list_final.append(last_name(case))

for i in range(len(list_final)):
    if len(list_final[i])>2:
        name1=' '.join(list_final[i][:2])
        name2=' '.join(list_final[i][2:])
        list_final[i]=[name1,name2]
print(list_final)
#[['BLAS', 'ZAPATA'], ['MATIAS', 'MANO'], ['LOPEZ FERNANDEZ', 'VILLAVERDE'], ['MIGUEL', 'CORRAL'], ['VIDAL', 'PE�A'], ['MONTAVA', 'ARCO'], ['CASAS', 'VALLE']]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! note though that your code has the same trouble as Wiktor proposal in parsing one of the cases. Names are indeed complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your requirements?

```python
import re

preposition_lst = ['DE LO', 'DE LA', 'DE LAS', 'DE LES', 'DEL', 'DELS', 'DO', 'DA', 'DOS', 'DAS', 'DE']
cases = ["DE BLAS ZAPATA", "MATIAS DE LA MANO", "LOPEZ FERNANDEZ DE VILLAVERDE", "DE MIGUEL DEL CORRAL", "VIDAL DE LA PENA SOLIS", "MONTAVA DEL ARCO", "DOS CASAS VALLE"]

def split_name(name):
    f1 = re.compile("(.*)({preps}(.+))".format(preps = "(" + " |".join(preposition_lst) + ")"))
    m1 = f1.match(case)

    if m1:
        if len(m1.group(1)) != 0:
            return m1.group(1).strip(), m1.group(2).strip()
        else:
            return " ".join(name.split()[:-1]), name.split()[-1]
    else:
        return " ".join(name.split()[:-1]), name.split()[-1]

for case in cases:
    first, second = split_name(case)
    print("{} --> name 1 = {}, name 2 = {}".format(case, first, second))

# DE BLAS ZAPATA --> name 1 = DE BLAS, name 2 = ZAPATA
# MATIAS DE LA MANO --> name 1 = MATIAS, name 2 = DE LA MANO
# LOPEZ FERNANDEZ DE VILLAVERDE --> name 1 = LOPEZ FERNANDEZ, name 2 = DE VILLAVERDE
# DE MIGUEL DEL CORRAL --> name 1 = DE MIGUEL, name 2 = DEL CORRAL
# VIDAL DE LA PENA SOLIS --> name 1 = VIDAL, name 2 = DE LA PENA SOLIS
# MONTAVA DEL ARCO --> name 1 = MONTAVA, name 2 = DEL ARCO
# DOS CASAS VALLE --> name 1 = DOS CASAS, name 2 = VALLE
```